# Convert .doc files in .docx in windows programatically using Python

Tags: docx, python-docx

I tried below code but it is giving me win32com Import Error

```
import win32com
word = win32com.Dispatch("Word.application")

import glob, os
os.chdir(%doc folder path%)
for file in glob.glob("*.doc"):
    file=%doc folder path%+'\\'+file
    print(file)
    doc = word.Documents.Open(file)
    file = file.replace('.doc','.docx')
    file = file.replace('DOCX_F', 'docx_files')
    doc.SaveAs(file, 16)
word.Quit()
```

But when I tried to install the same module it is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try win32com.client instead of just win32com

```
import win32com.client
word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.application")
```